# get max length of characters of a value from json jquery without loop?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json, i want to get maximum count of characters from any value under a specific tag without each or for loop, is it possible?

```
{
  "Language": {
"ru": [
  {
    "from": "set",
    "to": 444
  },
  {
    "from": "sc",
    "to": 222
  }
],
"he": [
  {
    "from": "trdsss",
    "to": 3333333
  },
  {
    "from": "ahsss",
    "to": 55555
  }
 ]
 }
}
```

Let me explain the exact requirement, i have to get maximum length of string under "RU", like RU has maximum lenght is 3 i.e. "Set" i don't want to get the string, just want to get the max. length. like for "HE" it is 6 for "trdsss".

i can do it by looping, but i don't want to go in that way, is there any other way i can get this. please help me.. how i can do it.

Comment: *"i can do it by looping, but i don't want to go in that way"* **Why not**?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, because this method will call number of times, so i am trying skipping looping

Comment: Is it going to be called repeatedly for the same data?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yes data will be same it comes from json once

Comment: do the loop once, and save the data in variable, next time if needed just return the data in var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't avoid looping. You can avoid actually writing a `for` loop by (say) using `Array#reduce` or `Array#forEach`, but something, somewhere, is going to have to loop.

When I asked *why* you wanted to avoid looping, you said

> because this method will call number of times, so i am trying skipping looping

and when I asked if those repeated calls would be for the same data, you said

> yes data will be same it comes from json once

So ***if*** it's important to avoid repeating the loops (it probably isn't, but it could be), you'd just loop the first time and then remember the result so you could reuse it in subsequent calls. That's straightforward to write.

Comment: T.J i need it for different tag selections like for RU the value should be 3, for HE it should be 6. but the data will be same always

Comment: @RamSingh: Right. So, again, figure it out the first time you're called for that information and store it somewhere, keyed by the parameters. The next time you're called for it, see if you have it stored, and if so return that.

Comment: it means i have to take n number of variable as much tags i have in json, then store their maximum value in those to use later.. is so? please clear if i mis understood